# how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it

Tags: javascript

This might just be a silly question,With jQuery we all know the wonderful

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/popup.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/popup.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       statcode(); //getting it from popup.js
    });
</script>
```

This is my popup.js:

```
"use strict";
/*jslint browser:true */
/*global $,jQuery,alert*/
function closeme() {
    $("#lbox").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#bg").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".listboxdatabank").css("visibility", "visible");
}
function statcode() {
    var myheight, mywidth, windowWidth, windowHeight, objheight, objwidth, posx, posy;
    myheight = $(document).height();
    mywidth = $(document).width();
    windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    objheight = $("#lbox").height();
    objwidth = $("#lbox").width();
    posx = (windowWidth / 2) - (objwidth / 2);
    posy = (windowHeight / 2) - (objheight / 2);
    $(".listboxdatabank").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $("#bg").css({"width" : mywidth, "height" : myheight});
    $("#lbox").css({"left" : posx, "top" : posy});
    $("#lbox").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#bg").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#bg").fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
}
```

But when am running it, giving the 
**ReferenceError: statcode is not defined**

Comment: Are you sure `popup.js` has loaded?

Comment: Why are you including two different versions of jQuery?

Comment: Exactly, are you sure its script src is pointing to the right file ? Check if no 404 occurred in your consoles network log

Comment: I am not able to load the popup.js, getting error SyntaxError: illegal character for popup.js

Comment: Well that's the problem then and not the document ready code, isn't it?

Comment: afaik, `use strict` has to be within a function.

Comment: @Andy It can also be at the start of the script so it affects the entire file.

Comment: but what wrong with the js file

Comment: getting this error for popup.js at line 1 
≵獥⁳瑲楣琢㬍ਯ⩪獬楮琠扲潷獥爺瑲略‪⼍ਯ⩧汯扡氠␬橑略特ⱡ汥牴⨯ഊ晵湣瑩潮⁣汯獥浥⠩⁻ഊ††␨∣汢潸∩⹦慤敏畴⠢獬潷∩

Comment: @Juhana, good to know. I've only used it within a module function to that effect.

Comment: @spt [Interesting](http://translate.google.fr/#auto/en/%E2%89%B5%E7%8D%A5%E2%81%B3%E7%91%B2%E6%A5%A3%E7%90%A2%E3%AC%8D%E0%A8%AF%E2%A9%AA%E7%8D%AC%E6%A5%AE%E7%90%A0%E6%89%B2%E6%BD%B7%E7%8D%A5%E7%88%BA%E7%91%B2%E7%95%A5%E2%80%AA%E2%BC%8D%E0%A8%AF%E2%A9%A7%E6%B1%AF%E6%89%A1%E6%B0%A0%E2%90%AC%E6%A9%91%E7%95%A5%E7%89%B9%E2%B1%A1%E6%B1%A5%E7%89%B4%E2%A8%AF%E0%B4%8A%E6%99%B5%E6%B9%A3%E7%91%A9%E6%BD%AE%E2%81%A3%E6%B1%AF%E7%8D%A5%E6%B5%A5%E2%A0%A9%E2%81%BB%E0%B4%8A%E2%80%A0%E2%80%A0%E2%90%A8%E2%88%A3%E6%B1%A2%E6%BD%B8%E2%88%A9%E2%B9%A6%E6%85%A4%E6%95%8F%E7%95%B4%E2%A0%A2%E7%8D%AC%E6%BD%B7%E2%88%A9)

Comment: @Juhana it is showing for all the js files

Comment: @dystroy it is showing for all the js files

Comment: @spt Note that the position of your script element (neither in head or body) is illegal according to w3.org

Comment: Something something tinkling of cut gems...

Comment: @dystroy how to resolve it, i tried different ways, but no solution

Comment: @spt I don't know where lies your problem (otherwise I would have answered). It might be a server or proxy problem. The fact I don't understand Chinese doesn't help.

Comment: @dystroy once can you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515907/firefox-does-not-load-css-and-js-files-to-some-pages/20536329?noredirect=1#comment30718039_20536329

Comment: @Juhana Once can you check this link            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515907/firefox-does-not-load-css-and-js-files-to-some-pages/20536329?noredirect=1#comment30718039_20536329

Answer (score -1):

Or try something like this -

```
  $( window ).load(function() {
     statcode(); 
  });
```

This will ensure the function gets called when external resources are loaded